# Observer pattern forces imperative style

Tags: scala, functional-programming, observer-pattern, imperative-programming

I was looking at the Reactive Programming course from Coursera, which uses Scala to implement an Observer pattern. There, Martin Odersky says that the Observer pattern forces Imperative Programming, which we can see because the subscriber's handlers have `Unit` type.

He is saying that here: https://class.coursera.org/reactive-002/lecture/107
At 9:40

I don't really understand:

1.Why do the handlers need to have `Unit` type?

2.How is the Observer pattern forcing Imperative Programming?

Comment: Do you mind linking the exact video/time in which he says that? May help you get an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not reviewed the video posted, so I am basing my answers on the OP's original question.

Handlers are, by the pattern's definition, callbacks; as such, they have a `Unit` return type because they describe some *behaviour* that will be executed in response to the notification. This is the very definition of side-effect.
Hence the statement that the Observer Pattern is an instrinsically imperative pattern: **the caller of a function (e.g. notifyObservers(observer) ) does not care on the results of the function itself, but it relies on the side-effects it will have**. This is imperative programming.

As a side-note, the fact that `Unit` is the result type is not **strictly necessary** but, as previously mentioned, communicates that there is **no interest in anything but the side-effects**. One could, potentially, model the method generically and return some more meaningful type, but because of the way the Observer Pattern is used in practice, this will probably be ignored anyways...

Answer (score 2):

Because if they do have the return type other than `Unit`, the order in which observable calls the handlers becomes significant. Not saying that observable now should be aware of the return types and should be able to handle them, which is not the part of observer pattern.

In general observer pattern means that both observer and observable should have a state, because observer is designed to react to events in observable, and this pattern describes the reaction between the states of those objects.

If you go to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and read the observer pattern definition, you will find `in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,`, which has the word `state` in it, which already means that we do not have FP anymore and it cannot be pure